# Magento2: 500 Internal Server Error just in admin url when changed default language

Tags: magento2, error, admin-panel, server-setup, http-error-500

when I go to the admin url like (mydomain.com/admin) I get 500 Internal Server Error but it just happened when I switch default language to something other than  en_US when I change it to en_US everything is good and no error appended.

Answer (score -1):

This is because static content is not compiled for this language, and no previous user had this language selected.

When compiling static, Magento uses only languages that are required, and in order to determine this, it looks into database for used languages. Since there were none other prior to your change, only English was compiled.

Easiest way to fix this is to run `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` after switching the language, though `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` may be enough as well.

Comment: I did not try bin/magento deploy:mode:set production but bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy not work for me, and this error is just for admin page frontend is ok

Comment: In the output of the `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` did you see that Magento processed language you have selected? Also, make sure that command is executed after the language has been changed in admin

Comment: yes I see there is no problem in deploy command

Comment: What does the error message say? If it is not logged in Magento folders, than one from the server/php

Comment: there is no error log in both server and magento ,this is a 500 http error with no log!